# Code to show a string of text

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm in my first semester of college, and we're doing C#. I have to make a Winforms app that can convert between Celsius and Fahrenheit. I have all the code down (basically), but I need to have the result output to a label. I can send the answer to the label with `lblOutput = Output.ToString();` but I need a message like "[input] Celsius will is [output] Fahrenheit". I tried putting in between the brackets after "ToString" but I was getting an error.

I have everything else coded except for this. I have been looking for the last couple days to figure it out, but I can't find an answer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

The code that I have set up appears inside of a button. I have two radio buttons that saying that the value put into a text box is either Far -> Cels or Cels -> Far.

This is what I have coded in my button. If there is any way to improve upon it, please let me know.

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal Input = Convert.ToDecimal(txtInput.Text); //grabs the input that the user entered

    if (rbtnCelsius.Checked == true) //Test to see if the Celsius radio button is checked
    {
        decimal Output = ((Input - 32) * 5) / 9; //If yes, it uses this formula to convert the input from Farenheit to Celsius
        txtOutput.Text = Output.ToString(); //Outputs the message to the user, showing the Celsius end point
    }
    else //Says that the Celsius Radio Button is not checked, meaning that the Farenheit radio button is
    {
        decimal Output = (Input * 9) / 5 + 32; //Moves onto this formula, converts Celsius to Farenheit
        txtOutput.Text = Output.ToString(); //outputs the message to the user, showing the Farenheit end point
    }

    //txtOutput.Text = Output.ToString();
    //Commented out because it gives an error saying that "Output does not exist in current context"
}
```

Comment: I assume that a "WFA" is a "windows Forms Application"?

Comment: Yes. I had stated Windows Form Application in my question, and I didn't feel like typing it again.

Answer (score 2):

```
int fahrenheit, celsius;
// your code to set the two variables
string yourLabelText = String.Format("{0} Celcius is {1} Fahrenheit", celsius.ToString(), fahrenheit.ToString());

yourLabel.Text = yourLabelText;
```

[Here is a reference for String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).  (thanks to Lukazoid!)

Comment: Here is the MSDN reference for `String.Format` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Comment: Is "yourLabelText" something that I would have to declare? I have had issues declaring variables in the form (it tells me they are never used). I have edited my original post to show the code that I am writing.

Also, @Lukazoid thank you for that, it is helpful, but it is a little different having the code display text from a console and from a form. I am used to writing for console applications, so I am having a hard time trying to get it to work in a Form.

Comment: @MattMiller `yourLabelText` is declared on the same line that it is assigned.  You can take that out and just use `yourLabel.Text = String.Format(.....`.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you. I am used to writing my output text in `Console.Writeline();` so this is a bit of a change for me. The last Form I had to make only outputted the answer, which is why I was trying to use `Output.ToString():`

Comment: @Shark I was providing it as a reference for the `String.Format` method, not as a code example :)

Comment: @Lukazoid thanks for adding the reference!  I've modified my post to include that.

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you. I changed my output code to that, and it works exactly how I wanted it to. Although, I looked at the instructions, and I have to have the output as a label, not a text box. I tried changing the lines of code, and it works fine, except down in my "Clear" button (that I didn't post. It only has three lines of code). I changed the `txtOutput.Clear();` which I had before, to `lblOutput.Clear();` and It says that there is no extension for "Clear". I can post the entire error if you'd like. Besides that, everything works fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is about but if you need to format your output into a set phrase you can do this.

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal Input = Convert.ToDecimal(txtInput.Text); //grabs the input that the user entered
    // declare this outside the loop so you can use it later.
    decimal output = 0M;
    if (rbtnCelsius.Checked == true) //Test to see if the Celsius radio button is checked
    {
        output= ((Input - 32) * 5) / 9; //If yes, it uses this formula to convert the input from Farenheit to Celsius

    }
    else //Says that the Celsius Radio Button is not checked, meaning that the Farenheit radio button is
    {
        output= (Input * 9) / 5 + 32; //Moves onto this formula, converts Celsius to Farenheit

    }

    txtOutput.Text =string.Format("{0} Celsius will is {1} Fahrenheit",input,output);
}`
```

p.s. Do remember to use a try parse method to ensure that the txtInput is definitely convertible to decimal.

Comment: Basically, I have to have the code read one input from a text box, and I have two radio buttons, one that is a selection for the formula from celsius to fahrenheit, and the other does the opposite. I thought the easiest way would be coding it in a IF statement, with the condition being that the radio button for coverting to celsius is checked. 

the `txtOutput.Text = String.Format(...` has to display for both options, which is why I had it coded right after where I have my calculation. I have to switch the order of Cel and Far depending on what is being outputted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you care about that, but for some cases you can get something like 12.243333333 by calling **Output.ToString()**, to make it more user-friendly, you can make it like this

```
Output.ToString("F2")
```

Which will change it to 12.24. You can use this together with **string.Format** like folks suggested.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you. I didn't like how converting 36 Far to Cels was "2.222222222222222222". I had no idea that I could do that. Does putting in "F2" in the brackets limit it to two decimal places? That is very helpful to know.

Comment: Yes, it's parameter for ToString method. There are lot of other ones, you can find more details on MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.format to replace tokens like {0} or {1} in a string, or you can directly use string concatenation.  I'd like to avoid directly giving you the answer since you said this is homework, but if you look for c# examples of this you should be able to find your way.

Comment: That actually is helpful. I was a little confused before about adding in multiple variables into the text when I was writing console applications. Before I was writing code that looked like " + diameter + " to display a value. It seems it would be easier writing it with {0} and {1} and then adding the variable at the end (I believe it works like that). Honestly, programming is the only class that I'm struggling in. Posting on here was like my last resort to figure this out (I have spoken to my teacher about it, but I haven't got to ask about this yet)

Comment: Programming didn't come easy to me either, and I did a programming degree! I now work in the Nuclear industry as a software engineer, just keep practising and you'll get there :)